# Programmatically calling PreviewTextInput not invoking TextChanged event

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` that only allows certain characters to be typed into it; I'm handling this logic in the `PreviewTextInput` event.  If it's a character that's allowed, then the `TextChanged` event is fired, otherwise it cancels the `TextChanged` event.

I have another application that is opened on a second screen while this is running, however even if there is keyboard input while the other application is active, it should still update the currently focused `TextBox` on the main application.  To do this, I added a listener to the `OnKeyPress()` event on the second application, which calls the `PreviewTextInput` event on the focused `TextBox` in the main application.

Here is the code:

```
private void ImageEventController_OnKeyPress(char c)
        {
            object focusedElement = this.CurrentKeyboardFocus;
            if (focusedElement != null)
            {
                if (focusedElement is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox target = (TextBox)focusedElement;
                    if (target.IsEnabled)
                    {
                        string text = c.ToString();
                        var routedEvent = TextCompositionManager.PreviewTextInputEvent;


         target.RaiseEvent(new TextCompositionEventArgs(
                    InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice,
                    new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, target, text)) { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When this is called, it goes through the `PreviewTextInput` event, however the `TextChanged` event never gets fired even if it's a valid character.  Is there any reason why `TextChanged` is not getting fired when `PreviewTextInput` is invoked programmatically?

UPDATE:

I added in this code to the bottom of my `PreviewTextInput` event listener:

```
if (!e.Handled)
{
     textbox.Text = e.Text;
}
```

This forces the `TextChanged` event to fire and fixes the functionality when the second application has focus, however if the main application has focus it causes two TextBoxes to get updated when only pressing one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out how to invoke the `TextChanged` event from `PreviewTextInput`, but I did manage to accomplish what I needed to do:

Instead of performing the logic to validate the key pressed is valid inside of the `PreviewTextInput` event, I pulled all of the logic out and put it into a public function.  Then in my `ImageEventController_OnKeyPress` event I am using the `LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()` method to find the necessary control.  From there I call the public function to validate a valid key is pressed and if it is, I call the `TextInput` directly.